# Issue GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, c#-code-model

I just want to know the difference between last two lines

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 if (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

   string lstnme = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtLstNme")).Text;
```

and

```
   string lstnme=((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference in the result of both output

Comment: depends if it you txtLstNme exist at that position or not, if it exists at same [osition then same output, else output will obviusly differ.

Comment: check the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" and there is only one textbox with name 'txtLstNme'

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but I would suggest to check if the control is null or not before you assign the Text value

```
string lstnme = string.Empty;
var control = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtLstNme"));
if ( control != null )
{
     lstnme = control.Text
}
```

Comment: This is not true, it's not the same. If you have two textbox-controls and you select Controls[0] then you maybe don't get the one you want.

Comment: check the error                                                                                    "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"           and there is only one textbox with name 'txtLstNme'

Answer (score 1):

1. `string lstnme = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtLstNme")).Text;`
   basically means it is finding a control with Name as txtLstNme in your cells and then returning the text inside that textbox control.
2. `string lstnme=((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;`
   it means lstnme will hold the text of control at position 0 in your cells.

the main diffenrece is 1st one is looking for a [articular text box in list collection of control, but the second one gets the text of the control at location 0.